# jQuery handle/hide expected Ajax 404 Error

Tags: jquery

I use an ajax head request to check for a file. 
In most cases the file wouldn't exist and it would be nice to somehow prevent the 404 to show up in my debug console. Is there a nice way to achieve that?

Just to be clear: http://jsfiddle.net/kannix/FFLdP/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, unfortunately, you cannot.

404 errors are handled internally, you cannot suppress the error, not even with overwriting the error events in javascript or try-catching it.

You could write a serverscript to check if a certain file exists and call that one to check if the file exists before calling the file that might not exist.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks. We can return some messages from backend to let front-end know we cannot find things instead if throwing 404 error to hide that info in the web console (improve user experience)